# For each $w \in F$, show $\sqrt{w}:= \left\{ a\in F | a^n=w\text{ for some }n\in \mathbb N \right\}$ is finite

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Show that each element of a free group has at the most finitely many roots; that is , for each $w \in F$, show $\sqrt{w}:= \left\{ a\in F | a^n=w\text{ for some }n\in \mathbb N \right\}$ is finite.

$a^n=w = u_{1}x_{1}^nu_{1}^{-1}$ where $x_{1}$ is cyclically reduced word.

$b^n=w = u_{2}x_{2}^nu_{2}^{-1}$ where $x_{2}$ is cyclically reduced word.

$a^n=u_{1}x_{1}^nu_{1}^{-1}=u_{2}x_{2}^nu_{2}^{-1}=b^n$

$u_{1}x_{1}^nu_{1}^{-1}=u_{2}x_{2}^nu_{2}^{-1} \implies x_{1}^n=x_{2}^n$ (since there are reduced words , i can cancel first and last letter).

Then the first letter of $x_{1}^n$ equals the first letter of $x_{2}^n$ and i can cancel them and so on...

Then $x_{1}=x_{2}. \implies a=b$

Is my proof correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to write any $a$ as the conjugate of a cyclically reduced word:
$$
a = u^{-1} x u.
$$
However, <s>I don't believe the cancellation you applied to the equation $a = b$ is immediate</s> (I think I just missed the argument, see the comments), because in order to cancel elements, they have to be equal in the first place, and in particular have the same length. Here's what I'd do.

Instead, note that
$$
a^n = u^{-1} x^n u
$$
by cancellation, so that the length of $a$ only increases. Moreover, there are only finitely many letters in $w$, and we may assume $a$ to be reduced. By the definition of cyclically reduced, $a^n$ is reduced, whence

1. the length of $a$ is strictly less than that of $w$, because $a^n = w$ and $w$ was assumed to be reduced, and
2. only letters that were previously in $w$ are in $a$.

But there are only finitely many words that are no longer than the length of $w$ that you can form with finitely many letters.

Comment: Can you help me to deal with this problem ? I cant understand how to solve it.

Comment: Which step of the above answer did you not understand?

Comment: I get the idea that $a,w$ has different length , If it take $a^n = u^{-1} x^{n-2} u$ ? and I dont understand "by cancellation, so that the length of a only increases"

Comment: The length of $a^n$ is given by twice the length of $u$ plus $n$ times the length of $x$.

Comment: Yes, and this is incorrect , so i can define $a^n = u_{1}^{-1} x_{1}^{n-2} u_{1} ,b^n = u_{2}^{-1} x_{2}^{n-2} u_{2},$ then cancel first and last letter ($a^n=b^n=w $ reduced words) , then $x_{1}^n=x_{2}^n$ continue with cancellation then $x_{1}=x_{2}$?

Comment: @erez Hang on, do $u_1$ and $u_2$ have the same length?

Comment: Yes, i can suppose it , no ?

Comment: @erez: Probably, but I don't immediately see how to prove it.

Comment: @erez Perhaps one can take $u_1$ and $u_2$ maximal, by adding more "inner" elements if possible, and show that if the length was not maximal, then $x_1, x_2$ would not be cyclically reduced.

Comment: $u_{1}$  is an arbitrary reduced word, $x_{2}$  is a cyclically reduced word then $a^n = u^{-1} x^{n-2} u$ same with $b^n$, what i need to prove here ?